# How can you determine which side of an interview you are on?

Tags: american-english, word-order, collocations, transitivity

If you say "I will have an interview with Bob", it does not say whether the interviewer is you or Bob. How can you state that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to accomplish this is to use the word *interview* as a verb:

> I will interview Bob on Wednesday.

(That means you are the interviewer, and Bob is the interviewee.)

Alternatively:

> Bob will interview me on Wednesday.

(Now the roles have changed, and Bob is conducting the interview.)